# How to show the informations in "numeric up down" using combo box event handlers?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the text(or value) of the numeric up down,when I change the member of the combo box. I do like this :

```
private void cbProductName_ValueMemberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((int)cbProductName.SelectedValue != 0)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            txtSalesPrice.ResetText();

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(cbProductName.SelectedValue); ;

            float salesPrice = db.FactorRepository.GetSalesPriceById(id);
            txtSalesPrice.Value = (decimal)(salesPrice);
            float discountPrice = float.Parse(txtDiscountPrice.Value.ToString());
            float finalPrice = FinalPrice.GetFinalPrice(salesPrice, discountPrice);
            txtFinalPrice.Value = (decimal)finalPrice;
            txtSalesPrice.Value = (decimal)salesPrice;

        }
```

txtSalePrice and txtFinalPrice are the numerics

but this does not work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think that I am missing something, where are you changing the numicupdown? I see where you are setting txtSalesPrice and txtFinalPrice, are those supposed to be numicupdown controls?

Comment: txtSalePrice and txtFinal Price are numericuodowns

Comment: `ValueMemberChanged` isn't the event you think it is.  You probably want `SelectedValueChanged` if the control has a DataSource, or just the `SelectedIndexChanged` event in general.

Comment: As you said,I used selectedValueChange bu when I run the prpgram , compiler says that"the cast (id) is not valid" something like that.why?

Comment: You're talking about code I can't see.

Comment: I am talking about the second and five line in the code that i bring it above.

Comment: SelectedValue only works if the ComboBox has a DataSource.  That's not documented in your question.

Comment: It has data source

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Microsoft that is similar to what you are wanting to do.

```
// Check box to toggle decimal places to be displayed.

private void checkBox1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /* If DecimalPlaces is greater than 0, set them to 0 and round the 
      current Value; otherwise, set DecimalPlaces to 2 and change the 
      Increment to 0.25. */
   if (numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces > 0)
   {
      numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 0;
      numericUpDown1.Value = Decimal.Round(numericUpDown1.Value, 0);
   }
   else
   {
      numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2;
      numericUpDown1.Increment = 0.25M;
   }
}
```

Sample is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value?view=netframework-4.7.2

I would suggest seeing if changing the Increment will help with your issue.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with the unit of work class that you are using, so that could have something to do with it as well.